# A debugger for IronPython

Tags: debugging, ironpython

Is there a good debugger for IronPython?

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing with Visual Studio, you could use its powerful debugger; see [this](http://devhawk.net/2008/05/08/Debugging+IronPython+Code+In+Visual+Studio.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

SharpDevelop (http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) has IronPython plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I love Eclipse. I learned it over several years while developing JAVA, and as soon as I found out there was a PyDev plug in that was enough for me.

I would recommend seeing if there is a plugin for what ever IDE you are most comfortable with.